# How Python card text Component will change

Tags: python, python-2.7, pythoncard

Hi I want to know how the code works in python for the below

```
Def func1(self):
    self.components.mytextbox.text = 'Yes'
    while 1:
        time.sleep(100)
        self.components.mytextbox.text = 'No'
        if self.components.mytextbox.text=='No':
            break
Def func2(self):
    self.func1()`
```

According to me, first `mytextbox`'s text is 'Yes'. After 100 seconds, it should be 'No'. But for me, when I call the function, the `mytextbox` text is not updating with 'Yes'. It is always showing 'No'. What could be the reason?

Comment: Proper code formatting would make this a lot easier to read and potentially answer, especially given that Python whitespace is important...

Comment: The while loop is unnecessary, just calling sleep and then setting the text should have the same effect. I can't see anything immediately wrong with this code, can you post the code for mytextbox as well?

Comment: Actually i want to know how it works will that mytextbox is Yes before sleep if yes it is not working for me even i removed while also

Comment: _"I want to know how the code works in python"_. It doesn't work, because `Def` with a capital D is a syntax error. Please post your actual code. Posting code that _looks_ like your actual code isn't helpful, since you may be introducing new problems, or even omitting the original problem.